# How to avoid a situation where the system is too out-of-memory to even show or kill processes?

Tags: linux, bash, out-of-memory, system-recovery

I recently ran into a situation where a system was too out-of-memory to even run `pkill` or `htop`, or to even create a swap file.

(But somehow I could still SSH into the system, so at least I had a shell.)

I ended up getting lucky by noticing that I could run `ps` and `kill` if I don't run the login shell, but I'm wondering if I hadn't been lucky, what could I have possibly done to avoid rebooting, assuming I still had the login shell?

Is there e.g. to reserve a specific amount of memory for a particular executable to always be able to run? Or is there a way to kill processes from within Bash that doesn't require a fork?

Comment: look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process#125024

Comment: Probably this will help you: [how to create a user with limited ram usage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34334/how-to-create-a-user-with-limited-ram-usage)