# Limiting RAM for a group of users on Ubuntu Machine

Tags: ubuntu, users, ram, limit, cgroups

I have a gpu based system. Multiple users use the system, as a result, the RAM frequently gets fully utilized leaving no memory for myself. I want to put a maximum RAM limit on all the users except for myself. I have tried the following:

1. Create a group on Ubuntu using `groupadd`.
   Used `cgroups` to create a `memlimit` group on ubuntu as per 3.1 point in [tutorial](https://enotacoes.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/limiting-memory-and-cpu-per-user/)

   **Problem**: Apparently, `cgcreate` is unable to fetch the UID of the group that I created.
2. Followed this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34334/how-to-create-a-user-with-limited-ram-usage):
   Created a group `groupname` on Ubuntu using `groupadd`.
   Created a group `memlimit` in `/etc/cgconfig.conf`.
   Updated the `/etc/cgrules.conf` with `@groupname memory memlimit/`.
   Finally ran `sudo cgrulesengd`

   **Problem**: No errors but memory limit not working.

Comment: Read the manual page for `limits.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If [the unified cgroup (cgroup version 2)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#Unified%20and%20Legacy%20Control%20Group%20Hierarchies) is acceptable and you have the administrator's password, the following steps should work on Ubuntu **18.04** (I am not sure of older versions of Ubuntu):

1. Add `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`, run `update-grub`.
2. Make the following `/etc/systemd/system/user.slice.d/allmemory.conf`

`[Slice]
MemoryHigh=32G`

3. Reboot Linux. Then the memory consumption of all users, including you, is limited to 32 GB. To escape this limitation, start another shell by `systemd-run --scope /bin/bash`. The new bash shell belongs to another cgroup and is not controlled by the memory control.