# cgroup to limit memory usage of users

Tags: memory

I read this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34335/106248) and tried the methods suggested.
I edited `\etc\cgconfig.conf` like this:

```
group memlimit {
    memory {
       memory.limit_in_bytes = 21474836480;
    }
}
```

and `/etc/cgrules.conf`

```
user1   memory   memlimit/
```

but it does not work.

Using `/etc/security/limits.conf` abort the process with larger than memory threshold. I just want the process alive and send it to swap.
I am using Ubuntu, 18.04LTS OS.
I already installed 
`apt install cgroup-tools`.
[Here](https://enotacoes.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/limiting-memory-and-cpu-per-user/) suggest to use `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"` and update grub. Is it safe to update grub?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is safe to update the grub with theses options.
In fact, the kernel parameters you add, enable the cgroups to manage memory limits and the swap.

If you already installed docker, if you don't add theses options, you'll have warnings. It is also written on docker [post-install documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) at the end of the page.
On other distro, there was no need of theses options because they are enabled by default.

So to come back to your problem, yes theses kernel parameters may solve your problem.